# Update tickposition on zoom

Tags: highcharts

When zooming the graph the tick value positions do not get updated. How do I update the tick value positions when I click a zoom button or use the date span picker?

This is how my `afterSetExtreme` function looks like:

```
events:{
    afterSetExtremes:function(e){
        var min = this.min,
            max = this.max,
            chart = this.chart;

        chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
        chart.xAxis[1].setExtremes(min,max);
        $.getJSON('/api/foo', function(data) {
            chart.series[0].setData(data[0].data);
            chart.hideLoading();
        });

    }
},
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BnFAs/2/

Comment: Do you have any live demo?

Comment: I've added a Fiddle. Not sure why one of the lines is displayed outside of the graph though.

Answer (score 0):

In case when you need modify extremes, you should setExtremes as you have. But when you need to update ticks, you need to prepare your own calculating funciton (by [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner))

Comment: I was looking at that callback function. Will it get called when `setExtremes` is called? And if so, how would I pass the value to it?

Comment: callback of setExtrmees is event afterSetExtremes

Comment: But how would I get the `tickPositioner` to be called? I've added a fiddle.

Comment: Tickposioner is funciton, so it cannot be called but in tickpositoenr you can prepare function which will caluclate ticks. Becuase this funciton is called always after modification on axis (i.e setextrems) defaulty.